# How to get the unmatched array value from array in javascript with minimum complexity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, polymer

Hi I am new to java script i want some solution for the below scenario. I have a multidimensional array of coordinates

```
var coordinateArr = [ [[45.56,45.57],[44.36,44.37]],
                      [[42.26,42.37],[42.46,42.57]],
                      [[41.56,41.57],[41.36,41.37],[41.26,41.27]] 
                    ];
```

and i have an another multidimensional  array like

```
var  anotherArr = [ [[41.56,41.57],[41.36,41.37],[41.26,41.27]], 
                     [[42.26,42.37],[42.46,42.57]]
                  ];
```

Now i want to extract the unmatched value from coordinateArr  like

```
var unmatchedArr= [[[45.56,45.57],[44.36,44.37]]];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Javascript does array comparisons by reference so you can't simple test if an array from one group is in another unless they are the same object. You need to either test each value or convert the array to something that compares by value like a string. For arrays you can use `JSON.stringify`. If you make a `Set` out of `anotherArr` you can then compare in a `filter` with `Set.has()`

```js
var coordinateArr = [ [[45.56,45.57],[44.36,44.37]],
                      [[42.26,42.37],[42.46,42.57]],
                      [[41.56,41.57],[41.36,41.37],[41.26,41.27]] 
                    ];

var  anotherArr = [ [[41.56,41.57],[41.36,41.37],[41.26,41.27]], 
                     [[42.26,42.37],[42.46,42.57]]
                  ]; 

let keys = new Set(anotherArr.map(JSON.stringify))
let filtered = coordinateArr.filter(arr => !keys.has(JSON.stringify(arr)))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `filter`ing out the array elements that are not `include`d in the other array:

```js
var coordinateArr = [
  [
    [45.56, 45.57],
    [44.36, 44.37]
  ],
  [
    [42.26, 42.37],
    [42.46, 42.57]
  ],
  [
    [41.56, 41.57],
    [41.36, 41.37],
    [41.26, 41.27]
  ]
];

var anotherArr = [
  [
    [41.56, 41.57],
    [41.36, 41.37],
    [41.26, 41.27]
  ],
  [
    [42.26, 42.37],
    [42.46, 42.57]
  ]
];

var unmatchedArr = coordinateArr.filter(e => !anotherArr.includes(e));
console.log(unmatchedArr);
```

Comment: This doesn't filter anything because `includes` tests by strict comparison.

Comment: How could I not use strict comparison @MarkMeyer? (I'm kind of new to "strict" JS)

Comment: It's not strict js. It's just that when you compare two arrays they will never be equal unless they are the same object (not just the same value)

Comment: Oh, right. I see now. So should I convert the arrays to strings, which are easier to compare?

Comment: Yes, that's one way.